# AngularJS AnimateProvider causing scripts to reload

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I've been getting:

**WARNING: Tried to load angular more than once.**

in my Angular app. I've looked for unclosed tags and checked the order of scripts. In fact I removed pretty much all the HTML to be sure so now I have an empty page with just the scripts and css.

As far as I can tell the $animate.enter function is triggering jQuery to reload all scripts hence the warning. (I logged the XHR requests and found this is triggered by jquery-2.1.1.js line 8623. Put a breakpoint on that line and look at the stack. It traces back to angular.js 4363)

Anyone know what could be causing this?

jQuery 2.1.1
AngularJS v1.3.0-build.3181+sha.5b2a386

Answer (score 0):

This was because I had ng-view as an attribute on my 'body' tag instead of a 'div' tag inside the body.

i.e.

Was

```
<body ng-view>
    ...
</body>
```

Should be

```
<body>
    <div ng-view>
        ...
    </div>
</body>
```